# ¿Cómo evitar que se almacene más de una vez un nuevo elemento en localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Estoy trabajando en guardar información almacenada en objetos en el localstorage. La función es disparada por un evento click en una etiqueta "a". La función actúa correctamente cuando se guardan el primero y segundo elemento. Pero cuando ya hay dos elementos en el localstorage, empieza a acumular más de una vez el mismo elemento, es decir, si hay dos elementos, almacena dos veces el nuevo elemento, si hay cuatro, almacena cuatro veces el elemento nuevo, y así sucesivamente.

Este es mi código:

```
$j('a.a-links').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // compruebo si existe el elemento en LS, y si no, lo seteo
    if (!localStorage.getItem('Navegacion-Prueba')) {
        localStorage.setItem('Navegacion-Prueba', JSON.stringify([]));
        console.log('creando objeto en local storage');
    }
    var objectFromLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Navegacion-Prueba')),
        focus = e.target,
        categoryL1 = $j(focus).parents('li.submenu-li-first').find('.submenu-li-link').html(),
        categoryL2 = $j(focus).parents('.subsubcater-ul-full').find('a').html(),
        // console.log(categoryL2);
        categoryL3 = $j(focus).html(),
        // console.log(categoryL3);
        cont = 1,
        navObjRed = {
            "CatN1": categoryL1,
            "CatN2": categoryL2,
            "CatN3": categoryL3,
            "Cont": cont
        };
        console.log(objectFromLS);
    if (objectFromLS.length === 0) {
        objectFromLS.push(navObjRed);
        // localStorage.setItem("Navegacion-Prueba", JSON.stringify(objectFromLS));
        console.log(objectFromLS);
        // return objectFromLS;
    } else {
        $j(objectFromLS).each(function (o) {
            if (o.CatN3 === categoryL3) {
                o.CatN3 += 1;
                // localStorage.setItem("Navegacion-Prueba", JSON.stringify(objectFromLS));
                console.log('object already exists, adding 1 to counter');
                // return objectFromLS;

            } else {
                objectFromLS.push(navObjRed);
                console.log('object already exists, adding a new object');
                // return objectFromLS;

            }
        })
    }
    localStorage.setItem("Navegacion-Prueba", JSON.stringify(objectFromLS));
    console.log('setting the object in local storage');
});
```

Este es el resultado de mi código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A alguien se le ocurre una manera de solucionar esto? Ya he intentado evitar la propagación del evento, pero no funciona, pienso que el problema tiene que ver más con el localstorage, pero no tengo idea de cómo solucionarlo.

Comment: tu error se da aqui `if (objectFromLS.length === 0) {` porque un objeto json no tiene un propiedad length esto es solo para arreglos... cambialo a  `if(Object.keys(objectFromLS).length ===0){`

Comment: Pero ya está parseado, entonces sí tiene esa propiedad, lo comprobé en la consola. 
Tienes alguna otra sugerencia o idea?

Comment: si ya existe vacia su valor acual,    localStorage.setItem('Navegacion-Prueba', ''); antes de agregar el valor nuevo asi no se te acumulan.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré lo que estaba pasando, el lugar en el que agregaba el nuevo elemento al arreglo era dentro del bucle, entonces, almacenaba el dato la misma cantidad de veces que entraba al bucle. Entonces hice lo siguiente:

```
// evento
$j('a.a-links').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Compruebo si existe el elemento en localStorage, si no está, lo creo
    if (!localStorage.getItem('Navegacion-Prueba')) {
        localStorage.setItem('Navegacion-Prueba', JSON.stringify([]));
    }
//Obtengo la información del localStorage y creo el objeto con la información necesaria
    var objectFromLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Navegacion-Prueba')),
        focus = e.target,
        categoryL1 = $j(focus).parents('li.submenu-li-first').find('.submenu-li-link').html(),
        categoryL2 = $j(focus).parents('.subsubcater-ul-full').find('a').html(),
        categoryL3 = $j(focus).html(),
        cont = 1,
        navObjRed = {
            "CatN1": categoryL1,
            "CatN2": categoryL2,
            "CatN3": categoryL3,
            "Cont": cont
        };
// Evalúo si el elemento del localStorage tiene algo dentro
    if (Object.keys(objectFromLS).length === 0) {
        objectFromLS.push(navObjRed);
    } else if (Object.keys(objectFromLS).length !== 0) {
//Creo una variable que voy a utilizar más adelante
        var validator = false;
//Vacío el elemento en el localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('Navegacion-Prueba', JSON.stringify([]));
//Comienza el bucle y evalúo si el elemento existe ya en localStorage
        $j(objectFromLS).each(function () {
            if (this.CatN3 === categoryL3) {
//Si el elemento ya existe, sumo al contador y validator se queda en false
                this.Cont += 1;
                 validator = false;
            } else {
 //si no existe el elemento, validator se vuelve true
                validator = true;
            }
        })
// Fuera del bucle, si validator es true, entonces se agrega el elemento nuevo
        if (validator === true) {
            objectFromLS.push(navObjRed);
//Si no, no agrega nada
        } else {
            console.log('no adding new element');
        }
    }
// Agrego el arreglo al localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("Navegacion-Prueba", JSON.stringify(objectFromLS));
})
```

Muchas gracias a quienes me contestaron!